# How can I make a custom WTforms validator for a Flask app that restricts form to one submission per user

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, wtforms

I have a Flask app that has a submission form shown below, but I want to restrict users to only submitting the form once. The following is my code that does not work: the validation error does not go through and the user can submit infinitely many times.

```
  class WorkScoreForm(FlaskForm):
     wq1= RadioField('blah blah', choices=[(1,'Not important at all'),(2,'Somewhat unimportant'),(3,'Neutral'),(4,'Somewhat important'),(5,'Very important')], validators=[DataRequired()])
     wq2= RadioField('blah blah', choices=[(1,'I strongly disagree'),(2,'I disagree somewhat'),(3,'Neutral'),(4,'I agree somewhat'),(5,'I strongly agree')], validators=[DataRequired()])

    def validate_workscore(self, form):
        submit_id = current_user.id
        sub = Workscore.query.filter_by(user_id=submit_id).first()
        if sub:
            raise ValidationError('You have already submitted this form once!.')
```

Here is the route python code:

```
@app.route("/quiz",methods=["GET","POST"])  
@login_required 
def quiz():
    form = WorkScoreForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        workscore = Workscore(wq1=form.wq1.data, wq2=form.wq2.data,wq3=form.wq3.data, wq4=form.wq4.data,wq5=form.wq5.data, wq6=form.wq6.data,
        ss1=form.ss1.data, ss2=form.ss2.data,ss3=form.ss3.data, ss4=form.ss4.data,ss5=form.ss5.data, ss6=form.ss6.data,
        fam1=form.fam1.data, fam2=form.fam2.data,fam3=form.fam3.data, fam4=form.fam4.data,fam5=form.fam5.data, fam6=form.fam6.data,
        fr1=form.fr1.data, fr2=form.fr2.data,fr3=form.fr3.data, fr4=form.fr4.data,fr5=form.fr5.data, fr6=form.fr6.data,
        hf1=form.hf1.data, hf2=form.hf2.data,hf3=form.hf3.data, hf4=form.hf4.data,hf5=form.hf5.data, hf6=form.hf6.data,
        gb1=form.gb1.data, gb2=form.gb2.data,gb3=form.gb3.data, gb4=form.gb4.data,gb5=form.gb5.data, gb6=form.gb6.data,
        spi1=form.spi1.data, spi2=form.spi2.data,spi3=form.spi3.data, spi4=form.spi4.data,spi5=form.spi5.data, spi6=form.spi6.data,
        ws1=form.ws1.data, ws2=form.ws2.data,ws3=form.ws3.data, ws4=form.ws4.data,
        rl1=form.rl1.data, rl2=form.rl2.data,rl3=form.rl3.data, rl4=form.rl4.data,rl5=form.rl5.data, rl6=form.rl6.data,author=current_user)
        db.session.add(workscore)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your quiz has been submitted!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('results'))
    return render_template("quiz.html",title="Quiz", form=form)
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? You haven't shown us any error messages.

Comment: No error message, instead the form just submits as many times as you want without raising the ValidationError

Comment: Ah right. Your function doesn't return anything if there is no user, which is fine, but you may not want to raise an error when you can display an error page

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `validate_workscore()` needs to return something. Instead of raising an error, it would be better to return `True` and `False`:

```py
def validate_workscore(self):
        submit_id = current_user.id
        sub = Workscore.query.filter_by(user_id=submit_id).first()
        if sub:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

You also don't need the parameter `form` for this function.

Secondly, you don't call the function `validate_workscore` at any point, which means it doesn't run. Your view function could look something like this:

```py
@app.route("/quiz",methods=["GET","POST"])  
@login_required 
def quiz():
    form = WorkScoreForm()
    if form.validate_workscore():
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            workscore = Workscore(#all your arguments)
            db.session.add(workscore)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your quiz has been submitted!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('results'))
        return render_template("quiz.html",title="Quiz", form=form)
    else:
        return render_template("formerror.html")
```

I can't see a user_id argument being passed to the database on form validation, only an `author=current_user`, which is not what you query in your WorkScoreForm.